# How to simulate ctrl+enter

Tags: c#, keypress, enter, ctrl

I am building a win app that sends some pre-made messages to a chrome window (on a small chat window) button clicks.
I was able to do it, but now I want to simulate `alt+enter` when I click on a specific button.

Here is a part of my code (the button). As you can see, I have `SendKeys.Send("^{v}");` here, but it does not do anything...

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox7.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox8.Text)
            || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox7.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox8.Text))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(button5.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a message from the dropbox!");
            }
            else
            {
                Clipboard.SetText(button5.Text.ToString());
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox7.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox8.Text)
 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox7.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox8.Text))
                {
                    SendKeys.Send("^{v}");
                    IDataObject iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
                    textBox1.Text = (String)iData.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
                }
                else
                {
                    DoMouseClick();
                    SendKeys.Send("^{v}");
                    SendKeys.Send("^{ENTER}");
                    IDataObject iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
                    textBox1.Text = (String)iData.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int x = Int32.Parse(textBox7.Text);
            int y = Int32.Parse(textBox8.Text);


            Clipboard.SetText(button5.Text.ToString());
            System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);
            DoMouseClick();
            SendKeys.Send("^{v}");
            IDataObject iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
            textBox1.Text = (String)iData.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: Alt enter or Ctrl enter? Your title and question differ on that.

Comment: You are sending two commands, one after the other. It simulates --> Alt click. Enter click and what you want is --> Hold alt. Press enter. Realese alt

Comment: Ctrl+ enter, sorry.
I tried SendKeys.Send("^{ENTER}"), but it does not send the message pasted in the box, it just opens a new google chrome instance, just like i was using ctrl+n...

Answer (score 1):

According to [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys?view=netcore-3.1), you should use `"^"` for ctrl, `"%"` for alt, and `"{ENTER}"` (or `"~"`) for Enter.

So to send <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> use `SendKeys.Send("%{ENTER}");` or `SendKeys.Send("%~");`,
and to send <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> use `SendKeys.Send("^{ENTER}");` or `SendKeys.Send("^~");`